# DAOs - As a separate package or encapsulated in Service itself?

Tags: design, enterprise-architecture, dao

This question is to understand the pros & cons for keeping the DAO's with the service or as a separate package being consumed by the services.

> Consider a micro-service architecture. Let's say I have 5 different
>   services which constitute a System. Then there is a Database (MySQL or
>   Amazon DynamoDB) which these services communicate with.

There appear to be 2 ways to design the `Data Access Layer`

1. `Design a separate package which encapsulates all the DAO's for the tables.`
    Each service can add a dependency on this DAL and talk to the database. This would result in any changes being restricted to this package only. But would result in re-deployment in each micro service since all of them consume this DAL.
2. `Integrate the DAO's within each service itelf.`
    This would lead to only the relevant service being changed in case any database layer changes occurs (except thing like re-architecturing, or other system wide changes).

Both approaches seem fine to me. Could you guys share some inputs on them - which one to pick under which scenario, pros and cons of the 2 appproaches?

Comment: For scenario #1. Did you think to make DAL as shared library? Shared libraries are deployed into the app server and foreing apps only need to refer to them as a server resources. In Java there're app servers that allows to do it easly. What's your platform?

Comment: My company has its own custom frameworks. Typically I have seen teams create a separate library package for DAL which encapsulates the Database Architecture from the application layer. The DAL is then added as a direct dependency of the Services.

Comment: Yes. It's a good practice. But looks like a bad choice in your enterprise-architecture. However to make such lib a sharedlib would fit perfectly and no re-build, re-deploy would be needed of every service. Unless changes on services were demand it.

Comment: @Laiv could you refer me to some documentation on creating shared libs in Java.

Comment: Every Application Server has its own mechanisms. What's your container (JBoss, Weblogic, Tomcat? Sharedlibs can be packaged like *jars*, *ears*, *wars* and every App server deploy'em in different ways.

Comment: we typically use a custom app server based over Tomcat. So any references for tomcat would help.

Comment: [Tomacat 7#Shared Libs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html#Shared_Library_Files)